# Spark AR Project runs in Simulator but not in Instagram App

Tags: spark-ar-studio

i have published an Spark AR effect for instagram. It runs perfectly on all iphones, however, if i test it on my ipad, it runs in the Spark Simulator, but trying to run it in instagram fails. Using a preview link leads to a "This effect is not available" message, using the published effect it just doesnt show up and recording button vanishes (!).

Has anyone ever experienced such behaviour and has an idea what to do? Thank you!

Best regards

Comment: Update app, close completely.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to

1. App updates
2. Background segmentation thus try opening the link on a different device preferably a newer one.
   [From Spark AR](https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/articles/people-tracking/background-segmentation/#editing-the-segmentation-texture)--> "We've found that effects with both segmentation and the face tracker don't perform well. It's best to avoid using these capabilities in the same effect."